# acf field smart button

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use this plugin [acf-smart-button](https://github.com/gillesgoetsch/acf-smart-button) in wp. How I can include categories in the option links?

Only show posts, page and attachment files (multimedia).

Answer (score 0):

We recently changed the plugin to support post-types as an option.

https://github.com/gillesgoetsch/acf-smart-button/commit/1023dc158db0f965a1f4acdaec13b8044e167c3d

That might help. You see the adjusted configuration (when you setup your fields) in the screenshot.

[image: acf smart button post types]

Comment: I've made ​​this change , but the filter does not show categories

Comment: Right now you can only filter by post type, not categories inside a post type.